# Python Selenium Select Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am coding selenium bot. I have a problem. How can I select male gender in radio input in these code

```
<label class="gl-radio-input__option"><input type="radio" class="gl-radio-input__input" value="Male"><span class="gl-radio-input__label">Erkek</span></label>
<input type="radio" class="gl-radio-input__input" value="Male">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.gl-radio-input__input[value='Male']").click()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with xpath.

You can copy of the span's xpath and click